# started foreground service for musicapp,not able to listen song when not using foregroundservice able listen sound after using foreground not able

Tags: audio, push-notification, android-mediaplayer, foreground-service

not able to listen audio or song when I started foreground service

I created music app after clicking select button it will take audio file from my storage and it will play the sound .but my condition is after removing my application from recent apps I have to continue to play the sound ..for that I used foreground Service and I created notification  I am getting notification but the sound is not playing ..I am not able to listen that sound